# ¿Porque esta consulta no me concatena ni imprime el arreglo pero si un index del arreglo en php?

Tags: php, array, json

Estoy tratando de efectuar una consulta a MySql con php y recuperar ese registro para crear una cadena con un formato que despues usaré en Jquery. Despues de ver el código, veo que el problema es que el while no imprime el arrgle como necesito, pero si accedo a un index del objeto este si lo imprime individualmente:

```
$consulta = " select r.idReport,ll.codeEmpCall,pr.title,r.description,r.resolution,pr.operation1,pr.operation2,pr.operation3,pr.product1,pr.product2,pr.product3 FROM reportes r INNER JOIN llamadas ll ON r.idCall = ll.idCall JOIN plantillas_venus pv ON r.idTemplateVenus = pv.idTemplateVenus JOIN plantillas_remedy pr ON pv.idTemplateRemedy = pr.idTemplateRemedy WHERE r.idReport =  43";
$conexionMy = crearConexionMySQL();
$eje = mysqli_query($conexionMy,$consulta);

$acumulador = ""; 
while($infoRecuperada = mysqli_fetch_array($eje)){
    $acumulador .= json_encode($infoRecuperada).","; 
}
echo $acumulador;
```

Cuando inténto imprimirlo en pantalla para revisar si el error esta en la concatenación, tampoco lo imprime:

```
$consulta = " select r.idReport,ll.codeEmpCall,pr.title,r.description,r.resolution,pr.operation1,pr.operation2,pr.operation3,pr.product1,pr.product2,pr.product3 FROM reportes r INNER JOIN llamadas ll ON r.idCall = ll.idCall JOIN plantillas_venus pv ON r.idTemplateVenus = pv.idTemplateVenus JOIN plantillas_remedy pr ON pv.idTemplateRemedy = pr.idTemplateRemedy WHERE r.idReport =  43";
$conexionMy = crearConexionMySQL();
$eje = mysqli_query($conexionMy,$consulta);

$acumulador = "";  
while($infoRecuperada = mysqli_fetch_array($eje)){
    // $acumulador .= json_encode($infoRecuperada).","; 
    echo json_encode($infoRecuperada);
}
echo $acumulador;
```

El resultado cambia cuando imprimo directamente un index del objeto o una "columna" de la consulta (lo imprima dentro del while, o lo concatene, así sí funciona):

```
$consulta = " select r.idReport,ll.codeEmpCall,pr.title,r.description,r.resolution,pr.operation1,pr.operation2,pr.operation3,pr.product1,pr.product2,pr.product3 FROM reportes r INNER JOIN llamadas ll ON r.idCall = ll.idCall JOIN plantillas_venus pv ON r.idTemplateVenus = pv.idTemplateVenus JOIN plantillas_remedy pr ON pv.idTemplateRemedy = pr.idTemplateRemedy WHERE r.idReport =  43";
$conexionMy = crearConexionMySQL();
$eje = mysqli_query($conexionMy,$consulta);

$acumulador = "";  
while($infoRecuperada = mysqli_fetch_array($eje)){
    //$acumulador .= json_encode($infoRecuperada).","; 
    // echo json_encode($infoRecuperada);
    echo $infoRecuperada[0];
}
echo $acumulador;
```

Cuando cambio la consulta, no solo funciona la impresión del ARRAY sino tambien la concatenación. En base eso supuse que pudo haber sido la consulta la que no funcionanaba correctamente, pero al ejecutarla manualmente esta no lanza niguna excepción y si ejecuta la query:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás tratando de crear un JSON por separado para cada fila obtenida de la consulta.

Esta línea y mostrando al final del ciclo, te deja una coma al final de los resultados y, de cualquier forma, no es un JSON válido

```
$acumulador .= json_encode($infoRecuperada).",";
// Ejemplo del resultado:
// { fila1 }, { fila2 },
```

Esta otra, solo muestra un JSON de cada fila... tampoco es válido

```
echo json_encode($infoRecuperada);
// Ejemplo del resultado
// { fila1 } { fila2 }
```

Lo conveniente es que el acumulador sea un arreglo y lo conviertas hasta haber finalizado el ciclo:

```
// Crea un arreglo
$acumulador = [];  
while($infoRecuperada = mysqli_fetch_array($eje)){
    // Agrega cada fila al arreglo
    $acumulador[] $infoRecuperada); 
}
// Codifica el arreglo como JSON
echo json_encode($acumulador);
```

Ejemplo del resultado (JSON válido):

```
{ { fila1 }, { fila2 } }
```